# How to convert integer value to array of four bytes in python

Tags: python

I need to send a message of bytes in Python and I need to convert an unsigned integer number to a byte array. How do you convert an integer value to an array of four bytes in Python? Like in C:

```
uint32_t number=100;
array[0]=(number >>24) & 0xff;
array[1]=(number >>16) & 0xff;
array[2]=(number >>8) & 0xff;
array[3]=number & 0xff;
```

Can someone show me how? It is strange to me at first to program without types.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Sven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187699/how-to-convert-integer-value-to-array-of-four-bytes-in-python/6187741#6187741) has you answer. However, byte shifting numbers (as in your question) is also possible in Python:

```
>>> [hex(0x12345678 >> i & 0xff) for i in (24,16,8,0)]
['0x12', '0x34', '0x56', '0x78']
```

Answer (score 46):

This is kind of an old thread, but in Python 3.2+ now you can simply say:

```
number = 100
number.to_bytes(4, byteorder = 'big')
```

or `byteorder = 'little'` as per your needs. Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes).

Comment: and without variable: (100).to_bytes(4, byteorder = 'big')

Comment: and `.to_bytes(4, byteorder = 'big', signed=True)` for a negative int

Answer (score 41):

Have a look at the `struct` module.  Probably all you need is `struct.pack("I", your_int)` to pack the integer in a string, and then place this string in the message.  The format string `"I"` denotes an unsigned 32-bit integer.

If you want to unpack such a string to a tuple of for integers, you can use `struct.unpack("4b", s)`:

```
>>> struct.unpack("4b", struct.pack("I", 100))
(100, 0, 0, 0)
```

(The example is obviously on a little-endian machine.)

Comment: Depending on the machine this code runs on, the host byte order is probably not what you want. Use "!I" to serialize an unsigned int to network byteorder.

Answer (score 7):

You can pretty much do the same thing:

```
>>> number = 100
>>> array[0] = (number>>24) & 0xff
>>> array[1] = (number>>16) & 0xff
>>> array[2] = (number>>8) & 0xff
>>> array[3] = number & 0xff
```

or you can do something shorter:

```
>>> array = [(number>>(8*i))&0xff for i in range(3,-1,-1)]
```

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone looks at this question sometime later ...
This statement should be equivalent to the code in the original question:

```
>>> tuple( struct.pack("!I", number) )
('\x00', '\x00', '\x00', 'd')
```

And I don't think it matters what the host byte order is.
If your integers are larger than int32, you can use `"!Q"` in the call to `pack()` for int64 (if your system supports `Q`).
And `list()` or even `bytearray()` will work in place of `tuple()`.

Note, the result is a sequence of `str` objects (each holding a single byte), not integers.  If you must have a list of integers, you can do this:

```
[ ord(c) for c in struct.pack("!I", number) ]
[0, 0, 0, 100]
```

... or this:

```
>>> map( ord, tuple( struct.pack("!I", number) ) )
[0, 0, 0, 100]
```

But using `map()` starts making things a bit messy.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with `ctypes` as well. It's especially useful for converting floating point numbers to bytes. Example:

```
>>> bytes(ctypes.c_uint32(0x20))
b' \x00\x00\x00'
>>> bytes(ctypes.c_double(1))
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?'
```

Answer (score 1):

And for completeness: you can also use the [`array`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/array.html) module:

```
>>> from array import array
>>> a = array('I', [100]) # note that 'I' and such are machine-dependent.
>>> a.tostring()
'\d\x00\x00\x00'
>>> a.byteswap()
>>> a.tostring()
'\x00\x00\x00\d'
```

Comment: Thanks. This also works well with swapping a buffer: `def swap32(image: bytes) -> bytes:
    a = array('L')  # L = uint32
    a.frombytes(image)
    a.byteswap()
    return a.tobytes()`