# Write a number in hex format Python

Tags: python, hex

I'm getting confused with python, hex, int, LSB. 
I have a number.
Let's say

```
number=1000
```

i write it in hex format :

```
new = '%08x' % number
#000003e8
```

Now i need to print these number in these format:

```
\xe8\x03\x00\x00
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You mean you want to convert it to *bytes* instead? Then use `struct.pack()`.

Comment: There is a thread related to a similar problem.

[How to convert integer value to array of four bytes in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187699/how-to-convert-integer-value-to-array-of-four-bytes-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `struct.pack` for that:

```
print repr(struct.pack("I", 1000))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks that is exactly what i need! But it print in ' '  ('\xe8\x03\x00\x00') Which i don't want! IS there a way to get rid of them?

Comment: Found it: string = string1.replace("'", "").

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

That is not "hex" format.

What you want is the string that consists of the code points ("characters") whose values come from the bytes of the number.

You can do this in many ways, one is using `chr()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you simply say:

```
num = 1000
num.to_bytes(4, 'little')
```

like I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40996174/4511441)?