# How to convert uint32_t to unsigned char array?

Tags: python, c, arrays, uint32-t

I'm trying to replicate conversion `uint32_t` values to `unsigned char` arrays in python (I've already done it in C)

This is my existing C function:

```c
unsigned char *uint32_to_char_array(const uint32_t n)
{
    unsigned char *a;

    a = wrap_calloc(4, sizeof(unsigned char));

    a[0] = (n >> 24) & 0xff;  /* high-order (leftmost) byte: bits 24-31 */
    a[1] = (n >> 16) & 0xff;  /* next byte, counting from left: bits 16-23 */
    a[2] = (n >>  8) & 0xff;  /* next byte, bits 8-15 */
    a[3] = n         & 0xff;  /* low-order byte: bits 0-7 */

    return a;
}
```

If I were to do the following in gdb:

```
(gdb) p uint32_to_char_array(0x00240918)[0]@4  = "\000$\t\030"
```

And it's that string I'm trying to generate in python.

i.e. for a `uint32_t` input value of `0x240918` I want an output string of `"\000$\t\030"`

I've scoured SO but to no avail thus far, particularly this -> [How to convert integer value to array of four bytes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187699/how-to-convert-integer-value-to-array-of-four-bytes-in-python) but none of the answers seem to yield the input/output combination stated above

I'm using 2.7, but could use > 3.0 if required.

Update:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 0x240918.to_bytes(4, "big")
b'\x00$\t\x18'
```

Hmmm a bit different — I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face here but I can't see what it is?

So I can see:

```
>>> b"\000$\t\030"
b'\x00$\t\x18'
```

But how might one achieve the reverse? i.e.

```
>>> b'\x00$\t\x18'
b"\000$\t\030"
```

Maybe the question is how I can print a bytes-literal in octal rather than hexadecimal?

Comment: The `to_bytes` answer to the question you identify seems to fit: `0x240918.to_bytes(4, "big") == b"\000$\t\030"` gives me `True` on Python 3.7. `struct.pack('>I', 0x240918)` also works.

Comment: The solution you linked is exactly the same code. `bytes((0x00240918 >> i & 0xff) for i in (24,16,8,0)) == b"\000$\t\030"` is True.

Comment: Note that `b'\x00$\t\x18'` and `b"\000$\t\030"` are different representations of the same string.

Comment: bingo! how can I switch from one to the other? i.e. get my system to print b"\000$\t\030" rather than b'\x00$\t\x18'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> hmmm a bit different - i'm sure the answer is staring me in the face here but can't see what it is?

30 octal i.e. `"\030"` is the same as 18 hexadecimal i.e. `"\x18"`. Both of them represent a single byte in your byte sequence with a decimal value of 24.

You can compare the exact values in the REPL:

```py
bytes((0x00240918 >> i & 0xff) for i in (24,16,8,0)) == b"\000$\t\030"
True
```

[Check the Python documentation on string and byte literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

- `\ooo`    Character with octal value ooo
- `\xhh`    Character with hex value hh

These can be used in byte literals as well as strings (keep in mind that strings are byte sequences in Python 2).

I don't think `bytes` support an octal representation by default (the ascii codec always uses hex), but you can code your own:

```py
import re
my_b = b'\x00$\t\x18'
print(re.sub(r'\\x([0-9a-f]{2})', lambda a: "\\%03o" % int(a.groups()[0], 16),
  str(my_b)))
# Console result: b'\000$\t\030'
```

Keep in mind that the string contains verbatim quotes and the `b'` prefix, and it may accept escaped slashes as a hex sequence. If you really want a good octal `__repr__` the best way would be to create a loop and check for non-printable characters, convert them to 3 digit octal and join everything into a string.