# Vlang - convert int, u32, u64, f32, f64, etc. to array of bytes in LittleEndian format

Tags: arrays, data-conversion, vlang, binary-string

I have various variables of different numeric datatypes(`int`,`u32`,`u64`,`f32`,`f64`, etc) and want to convert them to an array of bytes.

For example:

```golang
a := 120  // int datatype
a_bytes = some_function(a)  // What to do here?

println(a_bytes)
// [ x, `\0`, `\0`, `\0`]   should be the output in little endian format
// OR b'x\x00\x00\x00' as a binary string
```

In python, it can be done as shown in these posts: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6187699/8363478) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36893206/8363478)

Comment: I believe you can do this with the builtin modules. https://modules.vlang.io/encoding.binary.html#big_endian_put_u32. It does seem this only works with unsigned integers though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [encoding.binary](https://modules.vlang.io/encoding.binary.html) as mentioned by [@Adam Oates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5920357/adam-oates) in the comments.

The following example is for 64-bit data. Similar functions are available for 32-bit and big-endian also.

To convert `f64` to/from bytes(`u8`) we can use [`math.f64_bits`](https://modules.vlang.io/math.html#f64_bits) and [`math.f64_from_bits`](https://modules.vlang.io/math.html#f64_from_bits) which converts the float to IEEE 754 binary representation(`u64`) which is later converted into bytes.

```golang
import encoding.binary
import math

fn convert_u64_to_bytes(u u64) []u8 {
    mut b := []u8{len: 8, init: 0}
    binary.little_endian_put_u64(mut b, u)
    return b
}

fn convert_f64_to_bytes(val f64) []u8 {
    u := math.f64_bits(val) // returns IEEE 754 binary representation of f64
    return convert_u64_to_bytes(u)
}

fn convert_bytes_to_u64(b []u8) u64 {
    return binary.little_endian_u64(b)
}

fn convert_bytes_to_f64(b []u8) f64 {
    u := binary.little_endian_u64(b)
    return math.f64_from_bits(u)
}

fn main(){
    i := i64(-120)
    u := u64(1234)
    f := f64(-1235.345)
    
    bi := convert_u64_to_bytes(u64(i))
    bu := convert_u64_to_bytes(u)
    bf := convert_f64_to_bytes(f)
    println('$bi\n$bu\n$bf')
    
    i1 := i64(convert_bytes_to_u64(bi))
    u1 := convert_bytes_to_u64(bu)
    f1 := convert_bytes_to_f64(bf)
    println('$i1\n$u1\n$f1')
}
/* OUTPUT
[0x88, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff]
[0xd2, 0x04, `\0`, `\0`, `\0`, `\0`, `\0`, `\0`]
[{, 0x14, 0xae, G, a, M, 0x93, 0xc0]
-120
1234
-1235.345
*/
```

> At the time of writing this article, [V](https://github.com/vlang/v) is yet to get a proper release. So the syntax, functions, etc. are subject to changes.